# Is SSLContext.createSSLEngine() thread safe?

Tags: ssl, java-6, jsse

I'm using the default JSSE provider in Java 6 (SunJSSE) like so,

`SSLContext sslCtx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");`

Can I call the method `sslCtx.createSSLEngine()` safely from multiple threads?

**Update 1:**
The code that's calling `createSSLEngine()` in this manner is run on the server-side only. Basically, a thread calls this method for every client that connects to the server.

Comment: It doesn't say so, but I've never worried about it and never been caught out. However you should call `SSLContext.createSSLEngine(String host, int port)` if possible, otherwise you don't get any `SSLSession` sharing.

Comment: @EJP I could only find [this old post](http://dev.mina.apache.narkive.com/VVCDUDuQ/sslfilter-and-ssl-session-reuse) mentioning the SSLSession reuse. However, it says that this only affects client-side code. Do you have additional info on the matter?

Comment: That's not correct. The server participates in session reuse too, and the SSLEngine only has this way of knowing who the peer is, so which sessions are with that peer.

Comment: @EJP I can confirm that the server is indeed caching the SSL Sessions when using the `createSSLEngine()` without any arguments. I passed `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:session` to the JVM when starting and got the following in the output: **%% Created:  [Session-2, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]** and **%% Cached server session: [Session-2, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]**

Answer (score 2):

The call to `SSLContext.createSSLEngine()` seems to be thread-safe. At least based on the fact that the application has not failed with any race-condition-related error.

In trying to find a definitive answer, I downloaded the source code of [OpenJDK6 b27](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/promoted/b27/openjdk-6-src-b27-26_oct_2012.tar.gz) and took a look at it. I’m assuming, of course, that this is the same code that is inside Oracle’s JRE 6.

When `SSLContext.createSSLEngine()` is called, it in its turn calls the abstract method `engineCreateSSLEngine()` on whatever implementation it has of the `javax.net.ssl.SSLContextSpi` class. In this case the implementation is `sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl`. The implementation of the `engineCreateSSLEngine()` method provided by `SSLContextImpl` simply returns a new instance of [sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/sun/security/ssl/SSLEngineImpl.java?av=f) by calling the `SSLEngineImpl(SSLContextImpl ctx)` constructor.

Inspecting the code, I couldn’t find anything that suggested a possible thread-unsafe operation.

Answer (score 1):

I can also agree with Elliot concerning the thread-safeness of `SSLContext.createSSLEngine()` in OpenJDK8 (based on analysing the code and performing simple tests).

I added this answer, because there exist situations when you HAVE to re-use `SSLContext`s (if you do not like wrapper classes or cannot use synchronisation): When connecting to a Wildfly application server EJB using SSL encryption, the jboss-remoting `EndpointImpl` decides to open a new connection based on a `ConnectionKey` that contains the `SSLContext` instance. So if you always specify a new `SSLContext` for each EJB call, always a new connection is used. The sad thing is, that the connection is considered "shared", so it is not closed after the call (but never re-used, due to the differing `ConnectionKey`s). After some time, you will only get many of those:

```
    Caused by: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:411) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
            at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:404) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.<init>(SocketChannelImpl.java:105) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
            at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:60) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
            at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:145) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
            at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.openTcpStreamConnection(WorkerThread.java:250) ~[xnio-nio-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
            at org.xnio.XnioIoThread.internalOpenTcpStreamConnection(XnioIoThread.java:247) ~[xnio-api-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
            at org.xnio.XnioIoThread.openStreamConnection(XnioIoThread.java:226) ~[xnio-api-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
            at org.xnio.XnioWorker.openStreamConnection(XnioWorker.java:398) ~[xnio-api-3.6.2.Final.jar:3.6.2.Final]
            at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionProvider.createSslConnection(RemoteConnectionProvider.java:246) ~[jboss-remoting-5.0.0.
            at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.HttpUpgradeConnectionProvider.createSslConnection(HttpUpgradeConnectionProvider.java:136) ~[jboss-remot
            at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnectionProvider.connect(RemoteConnectionProvider.java:206) ~[jboss-remoting-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.
            at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.lambda$connect$6(EndpointImpl.java:618) ~[jboss-remoting-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
            at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:617) ~[jboss-remoting-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:536) ~[jboss-remoting-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.remoting3.ConnectionInfo$None.getConnection(ConnectionInfo.java:83) ~[jboss-remoting-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.remoting3.ConnectionInfo.getConnection(ConnectionInfo.java:56) ~[jboss-remoting-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doGetConnection(EndpointImpl.java:487) ~[jboss-remoting-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.getConnectedIdentity(EndpointImpl.java:433) ~[jboss-remoting-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.remoting3.UncloseableEndpoint.getConnectedIdentity(UncloseableEndpoint.java:51) ~[jboss-remoting-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.F
            at org.jboss.remoting3.Endpoint.getConnectedIdentity(Endpoint.java:122) ~[jboss-remoting-5.0.0.Final.jar:5.0.0.Final]
            at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemoteEJBReceiver.lambda$getConnection$2(RemoteEJBReceiver.java:185) ~[jboss-ejb-client-4.0.9.Final.
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
            at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemoteEJBReceiver.getConnection(RemoteEJBReceiver.java:185) ~[jboss-ejb-client-4.0.9.Final.jar:4.0.9
            at org.jboss.ejb.protocol.remote.RemoteEJBReceiver.processInvocation(RemoteEJBReceiver.java:128) ~[jboss-ejb-client-4.0.9.Final.jar:4
            at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:454) ~[jboss-ejb-client-4.0.9.Final.ja
```

Re-using a static `SSLContext` fixes this.